# How to add a policy to S3 using Cognito Identity Pool to create private folders in the S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I have reviewed the existing answers on this topic and none of them discuss allowing a Cognito user to access a private folder in my S3 bucket using the user's `sub` ID inside of Cognito.

I want to allow a user that logs in through Amazon Cognito to access specific `private/` folders inside of my app's S3 bucket. I will use AWS Amplify to store directly to the `private/` folder to privately store the file the user uploads to the app.

The idea is that once a user has been authenticated with my Cognito User Pool and verified with my Identity Pool, the user is then assigned an IAM Role. This role should limit what the user can access in my AWS Account.

Basically in the policy I am sharing below, I am trying to grant access to the logged in user to the path `/private/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/`. Where `cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub` is the authenticated user's federated identity ID (their user ID), so that'll a user only has access to their folder within the bucket.

this is the policy I am trying to add to my S3 bucket but I have policy errors that do not let me save it to the bucket.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
        "cognito-sync:*",
        "cognito-identity:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::uploads-api-attachmentBucket-123456789/private/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:Invoke"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:*:123456789/*/*/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

These are the list of errors I am getting:

1. Ln 4, Col 4 Missing Principal: Add a Principal element to the policy statement. Learn more
2. Ln 7, Col 8 Unsupported Action In Policy: The action mobileanalytics:PutEvents is not supported for the resource-based policy attached to resource type S3 Bucket. Learn more
3. Ln 8, Col 8 Unsupported Action In Policy: The action cognito-sync:* is not supported for the resource-based policy attached to resource type S3 Bucket. Learn more
4. Ln 9, Col 8 Unsupported Action In Policy: The action cognito-identity:* is not supported for the resource-based policy attached to resource type S3 Bucket. Learn more
5. Ln 12, Col 8 Unsupported Resource ARN In Policy: The resource ARN is not supported for the resource-based policy attached to resource type S3 Bucket. Learn more
6. Ln 15, Col 4 Missing Principal: Add a Principal element to the policy statement. Learn more
7. Ln 24, Col 4 Missing Principal: Add a Principal element to the policy statement. Learn more
8. Ln 27, Col 8 Unsupported Action In Policy: The action execute-api:Invoke is not supported for the resource-based policy attached to resource type S3 Bucket. Learn more
9. Ln 30, Col 8 Unsupported Resource ARN In Policy: The resource ARN is not supported for the resource-based policy attached to resource type S3 Bucket. Learn more

I need help reviewing what Ive done wrong to come up with the correct policy for this bucket.

Comment: It looks like you are confusing S3 bucket policies and IAM policies. The Cognito users have an associated IAM role and that's where you configure their API Gateway, S3, and other permissions. I don't think you need an S3 bucket policy here at all.

Comment: check this out; im just trying to make this work: https://sst.dev/chapters/create-a-cognito-identity-pool.html

Comment: @jarmod do you have any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: the IAM role is a role assigned by Cognito. thats already working, im just trying to use that to name the private folder allocated to the user... lmk

Comment: You've created what appears to be a reasonable policy but you seem to have attached it to the S3 bucket. This is not a bucket policy. You need to attach it to the IAM role that the Cognito identity assumes. You should review the instructions at that sst.dev page and apply the policy correctly.